# Fetching an object in Mongo PHP library

Tags: php, mongodb

I use [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mongo.php) MongoDB library for PHP

If I use this code:

```
$db->users->find();
```

I get an associative array.

Is it possible to get an object as a result of find() method?

For example, in [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) I can do it like this:

```
$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call

```
$db->users->find();
```

returns a **\MongoCursor** object, which is an iterator you can loop over in a foreach loop as you would with an array. But each result you get from it, though, is an associative array.

http://php.net/mongocollection.find

So, to get objects instead you could cast each item to object prior to using it :

```
$list = $db->users->find();
foreach($list as $user) {
    $user = (object)$user; // object cast here

    echo $user->name; // use it as an object
}
```

Comment: This does not convert inner associative arrays to objects.

Answer (score 1):

If all you're looking for is an stdclass object (like with `PDO::FETCH_OBJ`), you can cast the current element:

```
$obj = (object) $db->users->find()->getNext();
```

Learn more about casting in the PHP manual:

- [Type Juggling (PHP Manual)](http://php.net/language.types.type-juggling)